Algolia index update from firebase functions
I've a manually uploaded index whose record is a array subset of my schema.
Now, that I've pushed the data to my index, I want it to update as per the changes in my collection.
I am using onDocumentUpdate() to track for changes in any of the records and using the below function to update the index with a new record.
const response = await client.saveObject({
          indexName: 'my_index_name',
          body: { new_record },
        });

But this is giving the following as payload
{\n  createdAt: '2024-12-19T08:58:15.735Z',\n  taskID: 892850766002,\n  objectID: '23376350002'\n}

My requirements are just to push any new records to the index as an object and change nothing. And also I should be able to edit a field of the index, that also I've to figure out.

try body: new_record 
